# How to create tag based collection filter in shopify without using any app

Tags: shopify

I want to create a Shopify filter on the collection page based on product tags without using any third-party app

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you share the code on what have you tried until this point in order to help you?

Comment: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/customize-theme-filter-collections-with-product-tags